# How to get Arduino to talk to two seperate motors wirelessly?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, wireless

I have an Arduino Uno and I also have two Servo Motors. Say I have a room that is 15 feet wide, and I want to be able to place the Arduino in the center of the room and control two servo motors placed at each end of the room using a button on the Arduino. Is it possible to wirelessly communicate with these two servo motors using just one Arduino and bluetooth transmitters/receivers? Or will I have to use three Arduinos, one for the center with the button and one for each servo. If so, will I be able to substitute the two servo Arduinos with an ATtiny chip?

Comment: Place the motors in two separate rooms.  Walk into room A and say "Hello motor, how are you today?", then go into room B and repeat.  Oh and do it while holding an Arduino Uno and you have done what you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need 3 "controllers", of which the one in the middle of the room might need to be a full-featured Arduino. Depending on the the needed libraries of your bluetooth receivers at the remote servos, it seems likely that you could use ATTinys in place of more feature-filled Arduino, but you would still have to think of the ATTinys as Arduinos or at least the glue controller to translate commands from Bluetooth to servo signals (PWM).

You could provide us with more details, such what particular bluetooth modules or transceivers you plan to use; some might provide an asynchronous serial interface, others might present an I2C or SPI interface, and given the small flash and RAM size in the ATTiny line, you would need to evaluate the code and associated libraries needed to operate it on such a processor.

The answer to your question is, "Maybe", given the small amount of detail you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to wirelessly communicate with these two servo motors using just one Arduino and bluetooth transmitters/receivers?

Yes. The process goes like this:

1. Can you get your Arduino to talk?
2. Can you get your Arduino to talk to one servo via wires?
3. Can you get your Arduino to talk to one servo wirelessly?
   R. Can you get your Arduino to talk to two servos wirelessly?

> Or will I have to use three Arduinos, one for the center with the button and one for each servo.

That's certainly one aporoach.

> If so, will I be able to substitute the two servo Arduinos with an ATtiny chip

It certainly can be done. Whether you can do it is unknown to anyone but you.